# If i'm not using 3rd party logins/services, will Oauth2 make my bakcend api more secure than basic user/password auth

Tags: node.js, security, session, oauth-2.0

I am currently looking to create a private web app with separate front-end and back-end on AWS using nodejs without signup and 3rd part logins, so generated user and passwords.  I have looked over a few post, seems Oauth2 only provide more security when I am allowing 3rd party login or services, because it is a authorization framework. so I have a few questions:

1. In my case, I don't think authenticate oauth2 token is anymore secure than authenticate hash password. So I don't need oauth2 am I correct ?
2. Other than SSL on transfer and then use session-token after user login, what other ways I can make the backend API more secure ?

Please provide links or examples(best with nodejs )

Thanks,

Comment: Question #2 is too broad by itself. As for #1, sounds like you don't currently need oauth2, and oauth2 is not an authentication (identity) solution anyway, that would be openid connect. Both oauth2 and openid connect have their usecases, but if you have a single frontend app (javascript or mobile) talking to a single backend server and that's it, that is not a usecase for either of those.

Comment: @GaborLengyel thx that's what I thought too, but what if I have mutiple frontend, for example 1 web app and 1 ios app ? If in this case do I need oauth2 then ? why ? thanks again

Comment: Basically you need oauth2 if you want to allow the user of "system A" to access resources in "system B" in a way that the user logs on to his "system B" account and explicitly allows such use for "system A". In special cases it can be used for different things, and openid connect adds identity to this (SSO if you like) with all the fancy features like federation, but based on what you're saying, I still think you don't need these, and these technologies would just add unnecessary complexity for you.

Comment: @GaborLengyel very clear . thanks alot!